# Encapsulation: Should all properties be private and protected?

Tags: encapsulation

After learning about encapsulation in OOP, I started to use only `protected` and `private` properties, share data via accessors and change properties via mutators.

Right now, I'm afraid of declaring `public` properties.

Is it good to keep everything `private` and `protected` or is there some cases where I *need* to use `public` properties?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't need control over a data/property you are exposing, you can use public property with no problem.

For all other cases (like if it's a property with only in-class use or if you want to expose a property on which you want to keep read/write control), it's better to keep them private and some time protected if you plan for your class to be inherited

Comment: Good answer! What about chaining in some language? I saw some code where properies exposed to gain chaining without fluent interface. It is just bad planned architecture?

Comment: It also depends on the language. In C# or Python you can always go back and make the field a property if you need extra behavior; in Java not so much; the future-change risk of exposed fields is much higher in java.

Comment: Let's say JS or PHP, what about them?

Comment: How come everywhere I got to work, It's considered super-bad practice to have any public property and instead have properties private or protected and have getters and setter that do nothing else but get and set ?